# How to convert a hex string to char?

Tags: scala

Does it exist a standard library for converting hex to char?

For example, I would like to convert `0x45` into character `E`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```
Integer.parseInt("45", 16).toChar // E: Char
```

For example,

```
List("45", "78", "61", "6d", "70", "6C", "65", "21")
  .map(hex => Integer.parseInt(hex.replace("0x",""), 16).toChar)
  .mkString
```

outputs

```
Example!
```